# Scala class members and constructor parameters name clash

Tags: scala, properties, constructor, field

Consider the following class written in Java:

```
class NonNegativeDouble {
    private final double value;
    public NonNegativeDouble(double value) {
        this.value = Math.abs(value);
    }
    public double getValue() { return value; }
}
```

It defines a final field called `value` that is initialized in the constructor, by taking its parameter called alike and applying a function to it.

I want to write something similar to it in Scala. At first, I tried:

```
class NonNegativeDouble(value: Double) {
  def value = Math.abs(value)
}
```

But the compiler complains: *error: overloaded method value needs result type*

Obviously the compiler thinks that the expression `value` inside the expression `Math.abs(value)` refers to the method being defined. Therefore, the method being defined is recursive, so I need to state its return type. So, the code I wrote does not do what I expected it to do: I wanted `value` inside `Math.abs(value)` to refer to the constructor parameter `value`, and not to the method being defined. It is as if the compiler implicitly added a `this.` to `Math.abs(this.value)`.

Adding `val` or `var` (or `private ...` variants) to the constructor parameter doesn't seem to help.

So, my question is: can I define a property with the same name as a constructor parameter, but maybe a different value? If so, how? If not, why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't. In Scala, constructor parameters *are* properties, so it makes no sense to redefine them.

The solution, naturally, is to use another name:

```
class NonNegativeDouble(initValue: Double) {
  val value = Math.abs(initValue)
}
```

Used like this, `initValue` won't be part of the instances created. However, if you use it in a `def` or a pattern matching declaration, then it becomes a part of every instance of the class.

Comment: A constructor isn't made a property unless it's a case class or annotated with val or var. It is available for use anywhere inside the class definition though.

Comment: Is there any kind of naming convention of the constructor parameters in such cases?

Comment: @Bruno - There are several naming conventions; I personally like the one where a 0 is appended to the name, since that zero implies a starting point, and it's brief.  (Underscores are sometimes prepended or appended, but I personally feel that there are plenty underscores lying around already.)

Comment: @Geoff It is a private property.

Answer (score 4):

@Daniel C. Sobral

```
class NonNegativeDouble(initValue: Double) {
  val value = Math.abs(initValue)
}
```

your code is right, but "constructor parameters are properties",this is not true.

[A post from the official site said](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8384),

> A parameter such as class Foo(x : Int) is turned into a field if it is
>   referenced in one or more methods

And Martin's reply confirms its truth:

> That's all true, but it should be treated as an implementation
>   technique. That's why the spec is silent about it.

So normally, we can still treat primary constructor parameters as normal method parameter, but when the parameters is referenced by any of the methods, the compiler will cleverly turn it into a private field.

If any formal parameter preceded by the val, the compiler generates an getter definition automatically.if var, generates a setter additionally. see the language speification section 5.3.

That's all about primary constructor parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider parametric field

```
class NonNegativeDouble(val value: Double, private val name: String ){
  if (value < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("value cannot be negative")
  override def toString = 
    "NonNegativeDouble(value = %s, name = %s)" format (value, name)
}

val tom = "Tom"
val k = -2.3

val a = new NonNegativeDouble(k.abs, tom)
a: NonNegativeDouble = NonNegativeDouble(value = 2.3, name = Tom)

a.value
res13: Double = 2.3

a.name
<console>:12: error: value name in class NonNegativeDouble cannot be accessed in NonNegativeDouble
     a.name

val b = new NonNegativeDouble(k, tom)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value cannot be negative
...
```

It's defines  fields and parameters with the same names "value", "name". 
You can add modifiers such as private ...

Comment: What do you mean by "parametric field"? And in your example, we can easily instantiate `NonNegativeDouble`, whose .value would actually return negative double.

Comment: @Rogach with "parametric fields" you can create fields with the same names as parameters names in constructor. I had improved my example.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `case classes` it should be:

```
case class NonNegativeDouble(private val initValue: Double) {
  val value = Math.abs(initValue)
  def copy(value: Double = this.value) = NonNegativeDouble(value)
}
```

The implementation of `copy` is required to prevent the sintesized version of the compiler that will bind the `initValue` argument.

I expect that the compiler is smart enough to not retain the «extra space» for the `initValue`. I haven't verified this behaviour.