# Scala: Construct base class via alternative constructor which extracts the parameters

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following hierarchy:

```
abstract class A(val x: Int, val y: String)
class B(override val x: Int, override val y: String, val z: Int) extends A(x,y)
```

Now I want to initialize the values from a configuration object but I want the actual values to be the original ones.
If I would do the configuration in B only then I would do something like:

```
class B(override val x: Int, override val y: String, val z: Int) extends A(x,y)
def this(conf: Conf) {
     this(conf.get("x"), conf.get("y"), conf.get("z"))
}
```

but I want to be able to do the same in A.
If I add:

```
abstract class A(val x: Int, val y: String)
this(conf: Conf) {
    this(conf.get("x"), conf.get("y))
}
```

I wouldn't be able to define B (I don't have the conf in the B default constructor).

**EDIT:**

To make this clearer:
The use case I have is a factory which generates the proper B (there are a large number of child classes). It does so by doing something like:

```
def getElement(elemType: String, conf: Conf): A = {
   elemType match {
       case "B" => new B(conf)
   }
}
```

Currently, I have a companion object:

```
object B {
   def apply(conf: conf) = B(conf.getx(), conf.gety(), ...)
}
```

The problem is that when I need to add a new element to the parent A, I need to go and change every one of the children and I have the same code conf.getx(), conf.gety() etc.

Ideally I would like B constructor to be able to do something like:

```
class B(conf: Conf) extends A(conf)
```

but I can't do this as this would make conf into a member of B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around some more I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116697/1547734) (also points to [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8384)) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889703/1547734). All three basically say the following:

If we use an argument without val or var and it is only referenced in the constructor then it does **NOT** become a member.

This means the following solution would work:

```
abstract class A(conf: Conf) {
  val x = conf.getX()
  val y = conf.getY()
}

class B(conf: Conf) extends A(conf) {
  val z = conf.getZ()
}
```

would provide the required behavior cleanly and simply.

Comment: Great that you solved your problem. I thought that you also wanted to have those constructors with parameters. One detail: _case class_ constructor parameters **do** become members.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [companion objects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects#companions) to define alternative constructors:

```
case object A {

  def apply(conf: Conf): A = new A(conf.get("x"), conf.get("y"))
}

case object B {

  def apply(conf: Conf): B = new B(conf.get("x"), conf.get("y"), conf.get("z"))
}
```

Comment: The problem would still be that the implementation of B needs to know how to extract the parameters for A. So if I have 10 B implementations I would have to do the extraction from conf 10 times (and update it 10 times if I update the parent).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the question about reflection/macros? or what do you mean by "extract the parameters"?

Comment: I mean extract the parameters from conf. Basically I have a factory which creates the proper "B". It does so by constructing B, setting its parameters based on a json object. So the factory reads the "type", and creates B. The base class A has most of the logic and most configurations go it it. I do not want to get all the parameters for the parent for each child. Instead I would like to create B by doing new B(conf) and have it set all the values correctly both for B and for A